# Disable the Sidebar on Product View Page

Tags: product-view, magento2.3, sidebar

I’m using Porto 3.1.6 for Magento 2.3.

In the product view page on mobile, there is a sidebar that is shown when pressing an arrow on the right. Please see the attached images to see what I am talking about.

How can I disable that sidebar? I don’t want a sidebar, instead, I want the information to show at the bottom of the page, without a sidebar, like it does on regular desktop view.

Please see the attached images. The sidebar I'm talking about is triggered by the arrow circled in red.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check from your theme's admin panel? there might be an option to remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, follow this:

- Go to **Porto Settings Panel**
- Then **Product View** Settings

  - **Page Layout**

    - choose **1 column**

Hope that helps!

Comment: That was it, you're a savior! It turns out the 3 Columns page layout was what I needed, as it hides the sidebar but still shows the extra info at the bottom of the page, exactly what I wanted. Thank you!